# Newspaper heading - grammar?

Tags: grammar

OK, here are a couple of recent examples:

> "How I taught my kids to get themselves ready for school"
>
> "Why the Australian Fintech market is taking off"

They aren't questions (no question mark), so what are they?

Comment: Uh, they're *titles*.

Comment: @HotLicks I’m afraid that *title* isn’t one of the more commonly recognized terms of grammar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are ***wh-* nominal clauses**. Nominal clauses are subordinate clauses that act like noun phrases grammatically, meaning that they function as the subject, object, or complement of a verb.

- I know why the market is taking off.
- I wonder how you taught your kids that.
- What you want isn't important.
- He asked who is going.

The ones used in your newspaper headlines are just the *wh-* nominal clause by itself, without some other verb whose argument it would normally be serving as.

These finite ones don’t require (or allow) inversion or *do*-support the way they would when used for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Newspaper headlines differ from perfect English, long ago each letter cost a lot of money because they literally had to manufacture each letter. In addition headlines use a larger font than the copy, limiting the number of letters that would fit in a column in comparison to the typeface beneath it.

In modern press work only the later reason is applicable but the practice continues and is promoted by style guides oriented towards newspaper publishing.

> Wikipedia: [Hot metal typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_metal_typesetting)
>
> "In printing and typography, hot metal typesetting (also called mechanical typesetting, hot lead typesetting, hot metal, and hot type) is a technology for typesetting text in letterpress printing. This method injects molten type metal into a mold that has the shape of one or more glyphs. The resulting sorts or slugs are later used to press ink onto paper. Normally the typecasting machine would be controlled by a keyboard or by a paper tape".

Some examples of 'headline style' are discussed in The Grammarphile Blog's article: "[Headline Style - Read All About It!](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/38093/Headline-Style-Read-All-About-It)". Also see "[The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html)", "[AP Stylebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Stylebook)" (originally a guide for reporters, it has become the leading reference for most forms of public-facing corporate communication over the last half-century), "[APA Style](http://www.apastyle.org/)" (guidance for writing with simplicity, power, and concision. APA Style has been adapted by many disciplines and is used by writers around the world), and "[MLA Style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/section/2/11/)", amongst numerous others.

See also online tools such as "[Headline Capitalization](https://headlinecapitalization.com/)" which applies style guide rules to check headlines intended for newsprint.

---

> Q: "They aren't questions (no "?") so what are they?"

Ian, they are not asking you (they don't expect a reply) they are telling you the "how" and "why". Assuming the articles are truthful they are statements of fact, not questions.

Example sentences:

"Let me tell you how."

"Let me tell you why."

Example headlines:

"How the West was Won".

"Why Mortgage Your Home".

Answer (score 0):

A-ah! A google search later and I have this:

Pseudo-Cleft Sentences With Wh-Clauses

The pseudo-cleft sentence is [a] device whereby, like the cleft sentence proper, the construction can make explicit the division between given and new parts of the communication. It is essentially an SVC sentence with a nominal relative clause as subject or complement. . . .

The pseudo-cleft sentence occurs more typically . . . with the wh-clause as subject, since it can thus present a climax in the complement:

"What you need most is a good rest."

It is less restricted than the cleft sentence . . . in one respect, since, through use of the substitute verb do, it more freely permits marked focus to fall on the predication:

What he's done is (to) spoil the whole thing.
What John did to his suit was (to) ruin it.
What I'm going to do to him is (to) teach him a lesson.
In each of these, we would have an anticipatory focus on the do item, the main focus coming at normal end-focus position."
(Randolph Quirk, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik, A Grammar of Contemporary English. Longman, 1985)

"[W]hat is striking is that the wh-clause of the pseudocleft anticipates (or 'projects') up-coming talk by the same speaker, and . . . FRAMES that talk in terms of such categories as event, action and paraphrase."